# error CS1061: "PictureBox" does not contain a definition "HorizontalScroll" and "VerticalScroll"

Tags: c#, windows, forms, scrollbar, vertical-scroll

I tried to develop an application in Windows Forms C# using ScrollBars, and ran into a problem that no matter how you type in `rect.X = (int)(pictureBox1.HorizontalScroll.Value / zoomLevel); rect.Y = (int)(pictureBox1.VerticalScroll.Value / zoomLevel);` it does not work, I tried to replace `VerticalScroll.Value to vScrollBar1.Value` but it still does not work. Also connected `using System.Windows.Forms;` which has support for ScrollBars. Thank you in advance for your answers and help.

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
rect.Width = (int)(pictureBox1.Width / zoomLevel);
rect.Height = (int)(pictureBox1.Height / zoomLevel);
rect.X = (int)(pictureBox1.HorizontalScroll.Value / zoomLevel);
rect.Y = (int)(pictureBox1.VerticalScroll.Value / zoomLevel);

Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
g.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, new Rectangle(0, 0, rect.Width, rect.Height), rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}

bitmap.Save(fileName, format);

PropertyItem hScrollItem = pictureBox1.HorizontalScroll.CreatePropertyItem();
hScrollItem.Id = 1;
hScrollItem.Type = 4;
hScrollItem.Value = BitConverter.GetBytes(pictureBox1.HorizontalScroll.Value);

PropertyItem vScrollItem = pictureBox1.VerticalScroll.CreatePropertyItem();
vScrollItem.Id = 2;
vScrollItem.Type = 4;
vScrollItem.Value = BitConverter.GetBytes(pictureBox1.VerticalScroll.Value);`
```

Comment: Put picture box into a panel and add the scroll bars to the panel.

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a try.

Comment: He still keeps complaining about the lack of

Comment: The issue is the size of the object being larger than the container.  See answer with check mark and bottom of this answer : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/63d962ed-8cfc-424a-a5aa-2ed6442fd49f/hide-horizontal-scroll-bar?forum=winforms

Comment: Can you show your updated code (with the Panel)?